# Обнуление setInterval

Tags: javascript

Есть 5 картинок, а под ними 5 кнопок(каждой картинке своя кнопка),через `setInterval` делаю, чтоб каждые 10 сек переключалось на следующую картинку.

Проблема: как сделать так чтоб когда вручную переключать с помощью кнопок, таймер `setInterval` вставал в исходное положение? То есть при нажатии кнопок следующая картинка должна будет показана через 10 сек, а не через время, которое осталось после выполнения последнего `setInterval`(то есть намного <10 сек).

Может при нажатии кнопок можно как-то обнулить его например `timer=10000;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
intervalId = setInterval("some_func()",timer);
clearInterval(intervalId);//после этого слайдер ПОЛНОСТЬЮ остановится. Не забудте перезапустить.
```

Comment: Спасибо,получилось.